# pkey in mysql database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

From this SQL Statement, I'm trying to understand the use of pkey, we already have composite key as primary key, Can someone please explain this.

```
CREATE TABLE categories_products (
    category_id int unsigned not null,
    product_id int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id),
    KEY pkey (product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: mysql uses composite keys left-to-right. this means it can access `category_id` as a single index, as well as the composite key `(category_id, product_id`), but not `product_id` by itself - hence the additional index on that.

Comment: so the keyword `KEY` sets it as index, and `pkey` is the name of the index on `product_id`

Comment: thats it. it could be `asdfjfwafosdfsdf` instead of `pkey`.

Comment: the use of this second index is to speed up the joins between categories and products?

Comment: hopefully the below explanation clears up the benefits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of extended explanation, and going from your example:

First, lets set up the environment:

```
mysql>
mysql> create table categories_products (
    ->   category_id int unsigned not null,
    ->   product_id int unsigned not null,
    ->   somefield varchar(25),
    ->   primary key (category_id, product_id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into categories_products(category_id, product_id) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I've removed the foreign keys because they make no difference to this, and i've added one additional field because it makes the results slightly easier to explain. I'll expand on that after.

First we try querying for a particular category:

```
mysql> explain select * from categories_products where category_id = 1;
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories_products | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    2 |       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and we can see from the result that it is indeed using the `PRIMARY` key, and examining only `2` rows, because the index knows that's all that matches the `where` constraint.

Our next test queries both product AND category:

```
mysql> explain select * from categories_products where category_id = 1 and product_id = 1;
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories_products | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const,const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and once again we can see that the PRIMARY key is being used, but this time its even better, it's only returning one row.

Next, lets try looking at just a product:

```
mysql> explain select * from categories_products where product_id = 1;
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories_products | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This time, the query was unable to find a suitable index to use, so had to narrow the results using `where`. This is less efficient than if it were able to perform an index lookup.

Why is this the case? Why could the optimiser use `category_id` but not `product_id` even tho they are both in the composite index? Because MySQL reads that index from left to right.  Consider a large composite index, `(f1, f2, f3, f4)`. This implicitly gives you access to these additional indexes, `(f1)`, `(f1, f2)`, `(f1, f2, f3)`.

Now lets add your pkey index in there and see what happens.

```
mysql> create index pkey on categories_products(product_id);
explain select * from categories_products where product_id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> explain select * from categories_products where product_id = 1;
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories_products | ref  | pkey          | pkey | 4       | const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

And there we go, the same query as before is now able to be performed using an index as well.

And now to why I added an additional field.  When the primary key covers the entire table, as it did in this case, any query is going to read the entire result from the index, rather than the table, and this may give a somewhat misleading entry in the explain results. For example if i remove that additional field, and the pkey index, and rerun the query, these are the results:

```
mysql> explain select * from categories_products where product_id = 1;
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories_products | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now at first glance it seems that the PRIMARY index is being used, but on closer examination we see it is still examining the whole table (3 rows), and limiting the result with `where`, as well as the index.

Anyway, this is why you need the index on `product_id`

Comment: Hi Pala, building on the knowledge gained here, I'm interested to get to know more about having additional indexes `(f1, f2, f3, f4)`, like how do I create indexes in workbench, should I go like this `PK-> (f1, f2, f3, f4)`, `Index1 (f2, f3, f4)`, `index2 (f3, f4)`, `index 3(f4)` or how, just stretching out knowledge gained in here. Thanks again for a wonderful answer.

Comment: You should pick your indexes based on your needs - if the fields are used as join criteria - they should have an index. If the fields are frequently used in `where` criteria, they should also probably be indexed.  If fields are used _together_ in clauses, they should be indexed _together_.  eg `where fielda = 1 and fieldb = 2` is an indicator you should have an index on `(fielda, fieldb)`.  Keep in mind that mysql is usually only going to use one index per table reference in a query.